# Why the formula below are critically-damped second-order linear systems?

Tags: speech-processing, speech, math

This is part formula of command-response model (Fujisaki Model)：

```
Analysis and synthesis of fundamental frequency contours of Standard Chinese using the command–response model
```

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167639305001706
 Why they are critically-damped second-order linear systems?

[image]

Comment: i have no idea what $G_\mathrm{t}(t)$ is.  it is **not** the impulse response of an LTI system with that $\min[.]$ function in there.  the reason the $G_\mathrm{p}(t)$ is critically damped is that the expression with form $h(t) \ = \ t \ e^{-\alpha t}$ is the inverse Laplace Transform of something like $$ H(s) \ = \ \frac{1}{(s+\alpha)^2} $$  anything less damped than that will have a sinusoid in the impulse response (it "rings").  anything more damped than that has two decaying exponential functions (with different $\alpha$).

Comment: What do you mean by "s" in the denominator of your formula?

Comment: [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)